# Custom notification: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths

Tags: android, notifications, runtimeexception

I'm trying to use custom notifications in my Android application using Google's sample from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) (section [Creating a Custom Notification Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView)).
Since I'm using this exact code I got a `RuntimeException` every few times a notification is fired.

My stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths
    at android.os.Parcel.readIntArray(Parcel.java:677)
    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:369)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:110)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:90)
    at com.****.service.UpdateFeedService.notifyUpdateProgress(UpdateFeedService.java:266)
    at com.****.service.task.PodcastUpdaterTask.onProgressUpdate(PodcastUpdaterTask.java:63)
    at com.****.service.task.PodcastUpdaterTask.onProgressUpdate(PodcastUpdaterTask.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:432)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
private final Intent updateInProgressIntent = new Intent(this.context, PodcastListActivity.class);
private RemoteViews updateInProgressContentView = null;
private PendingIntent updateInProgressPendingIntent = null;
private Notification updateInProgressNotification = null;
...
    @Override 
    public void onCreate() { 
        super.onCreate();    
...
        this.updateInProgressPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, UPDATE_INPROGRESS_NOTIFICATION_ID, 
        this.updateInProgressIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     
        this.updateInProgressContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
...
    }

    public void notifyUpdateProgress(final int index, final int size, final Podcast podcast) {

        this.updateInProgressContentView.setImageViewBitmap(
                R.id.image, ActivityHelper.getBitmap(context, podcast.getThumbnailAsset()));
        this.updateInProgressContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "some msg");
        this.updateInProgressContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, podcast.getName());
        this.updateInProgressNotification.contentView = this.updateInProgressContentView;       
        this.updateInProgressNotification.contentIntent = this.updateInProgressPendingIntent;               
        this.notificationManager.notify(UPDATE_INPROGRESS_NOTIFICATION_ID, this.updateInProgressNotification);

        ...
        }
```

If I replace the custom notification with a standard one (with `setLatestEventInfo()`) I have no problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I finally find the solution.

You cannot re-use the same **`RemoteView`** object like I did!

I was creating the `RemoteView` in the `onCreate()` method, then I was setting its attributes in `notifyUpdateProgress()`.

If I create the object in `notifyUpdateProgress()` just before using it, I'm not having exception anymore.

Comment: Sometimes I get this crash even with a brand new RemoteView, so I think it's related to bitmaps as mentioned by @Brigham

Comment: @Brigham's answer is correct. You may have been leaking `Bitmap` objects around your `RemoteView`.

Answer (score 23):

If you're seeing this issue, investigate the size of the Bitmap that you're using for the notification image.

If it's too large you may see this error, as well as an `OutOfMemoryError` on the Android system side.

Comment: m not using any image apart from app icon that too set in layout