# bad array lengths, notification manager causes phone crash on 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I launched app into BETA testing and multiple users with 4.4 Devices reported that the app causes whole phone to crash, phone pretty much restarts after app launch even though app doesn't even have such permissions.

The report I got from testers is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths
at android.os.Parcel.readIntArray(Parcel.java:820)
at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:348)
at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:139)
at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:112)
at als.wakeup.Awake_Alarm$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(Awake_Alarm.java:272)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:279)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:208)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This works fine on 4.2, 4.3 but it seems that Galaxy Note 3 and Galaxy S5 which run 4.4 restart.

What could the cause be? Is it app related or could it be glitch in new OS?

Just found out it works fine on Xperia Z1 with 4.4 and no crashes. It seems that only samsung causes this, any tips?

Notification Creating function:

```
public Notification CreateNotification(double distance){


    Intent notificationIntentStop = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), StopService.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntentStop = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntentStop, 0);


    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    Shortcuts shorts = new Shortcuts(this);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle("Localarm Running")
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
    //mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ico, "Stop", contentIntentStop);
    if(distance > 0){
    mBuilder.setContentText(String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(shorts.ConvertUnits(distance))+" "+shorts.GetUnitNames(distance)+" to Alarm."));
    }
    else{
    mBuilder.setContentText(String.valueOf("You've reached your destination"));
    }
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    Notification bui = mBuilder.build();

    bui.flags|= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), Intro.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        bui.contentIntent = contentIntent;



    return bui;

}
```

it gets called by: onLocationChanged()

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
    notificationManager.notify(0, CreateNotification(dist_difference-alert_range));
```

Comment: Would this do anything ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463727/readbooleanarray-throws-runtimeexceptionbad-array-lengths

Comment: and may be similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988018/custom-notification-java-lang-runtimeexception-bad-array-lengths

Comment: I saw those befure, but what bothers me is that code works perfect on all other phones and OS, even same OS but Sony phone, yet on Samsung it crashes.

Comment: Surely its about the memory

Comment: What's line Awake_Alarm.java:272? Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20830017/1777090) is issue in your case

Comment: The line 272:
            notificationManager.notify(0, CreateNotification(dist_difference-alert_range));

Comment: Can you add example code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @shoerat I've updated question with code.

Comment: Calling `CreateNotification(-1)`, `CreateNotification(0)` or `CreateNotification(10)` is not failing and I can see a "Localarm Running" notification in status bar on my Galaxy S5. Is there some specific argument that needs to be supplied for the error to occur?

Comment: Some key points:
*App works fine on all phones expect Samsung 4.4 Version android.
*The onLocationChanged is in background service, so it's calling notification from background service.

Comment: I tested the above code on Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 4.4.2 and showed the notification from a background service. The only difference is that I did not wait for location change.

Comment: Well so what could it be? Is there any alternative way I could get this to work?

Comment: It looks like a bug in the IPC implementation. From the id you pass in notify, an array of length 1 called idOut will be created in NotificationManager. Then this will call an implementation of INotificationManager (basically a Binder) through IPC marshalling that array. When Parcel unmarshalls the same array, its size does not match with what it expects and thus it throws an Exception. That's my best guess from the framework source code, but I have no idea if it can be fixed at all

Comment: If only this was reproducible locally...:)

Comment: @ozbek Did you end up finding a workout for this crash? I'm running into this problem.

Comment: @Marco: No, I never was able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [issue in Android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75096). Unfortunately, I don't think you can do anything about it.

Comment: Also got this crash on Android 4.3 only.