# How to dismiss notification without intent?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I want to display a notification inside the app that disappears when the notification is tapped without starting an activity.

I use an empty intent and it works:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setTicker(text);
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

However, there are some crashes:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths
    at android.os.Parcel.readIntArray(Parcel.java:789)
    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:339)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:139)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:112)
    ...
```

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655204/1870795) the crashes seem to happen because `intent` is not starting an activity.

A notification can be dismissed by its ID, but I cannot dismiss it when there is no activity to start and call the dismiss method.

How can I dismiss the notification on tap inside the app without using an empty intent?

---

#### Update:

According to [this SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415069/bad-array-lengths-notification-manager-causes-phone-crash-on-4-4) it seems to be an Android issue. The crashes I got reported also happened on Android 4.3.

#### Update 2:

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592030/1870795) it seems to be due to a too large bitmap set with `setLargeIcon`. So I am reducing the bitmap size now with Glide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an intent which calls a `BroadcastReceiver` which then cancels the notification.

Your `PendingIntent`can be created like this:

```java
private PendingIntent getCancelNotificationIntent() {
    Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(context, CancelNotification.class);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

The `CancelNotification.java` class would look similar to this:

```java
public class CancelNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
`NOTIFICATION_ID` is a constant you define and pass to the `NotificationManager` like this:

```java
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, yourNotificationObject);
```

**NOTE**: don't forget to register the receiver in your manifest file like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.package.CancelNotification" />
```

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It's a constant you define when publishing the notification via `NotificationManager`: `notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, yourNotificationObject);`

Comment: If someone finds this answer, if you have multiple notifications, your requestCode in PendingIntent should be unique (ex. use id of your notification).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to start an activity when users tap the notification you can build an pending intent which sends a broadcast or start a service.

Here is an example:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12, new Intent("any intent action"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Answer (score 1):

But what prevents your activity to have implementation like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
```

with additional nodisplay theme in manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

It'd be simply a [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) one.