# On click on button of notification without opening app

Tags: android, notifications

I am using alarm manager to send a notification at particular time using this code:-

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(RemindersList.this, NotifierAlarm.class);
 intent.putExtra("Message",message);
 PendingIntent intent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(RemindersList.this, reminders.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), intent1);

 Toast.makeText(RemindersList.this, "Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In manifest receiver is :-
`<receiver android:name="com.example.package.NotifierAlarm" />`

and the NotifierAlarm class is :-

```
public class NotifierAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


 Uri alarmsound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent1);

    PendingIntent intent2 = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "9");

    NotificationChannel channel = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        channel = new NotificationChannel("channel_01", "ch", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    }

  
    Notification notification =
             builder.setContentTitle("New Notification")
            .setContentText("msg")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(alarmsound)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentIntent(intent2)
            .setChannelId("my_channel_01")
            .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Here I want to add a button in notification with associative on click so that when user click on that button then some specific code should run without opening the app and then notification disappears
that is i want something like **Done/completed** button of event

Comment: [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Actions) are indeed a good place to start @PRANAV SINGH

Comment: @Sekiro I  already have a look on official docs they were suggesting using broadcast receiver but since I have one therefore that method was not work for me

Comment: you can have any number of broadcast receiver, just make a new one and add the code to run in background.

Comment: android studio is just an IDE, it just helps you to write your code, so unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE specifically, there's no need to include the tag

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56200802/10827064) will answer your question

Comment: @oemel09 thanks your answer perfectly for me but that had some missing part which is edited by me kindly check and give approval

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56200802/13694485) answer is perfectly work for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove `PendingIntent` in your `NotificationComat`, then the app will not navigation to `MainActivity` anymore.

And also, it is encourage for user to swipe left/right to dismiss the notification like any other Android user does.

Comment: I want something like dismiss button but doesn't want dismiss button actually I want to do some background work when user click on that button otherwise notification will work as ordinary notification

Comment: Can try if remove ```PendingIntent```? but question is, if you didnt start your app, how can you run background task?

Comment: using broadcast receiver...for more information you can read the official docs whose link is commented by sekiro